# I can't figure out syntax error in complex join statement mysql 8.0

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I recently update mysql to 8.0. Since this update a syntax error is reported in this query:

```
UPDATE
  MinMaxAvg AS tar
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      SUBSTR(YYYYDD, 1, 8) AS timestamp,
      ROUND(AVG(rainfall), 1) AS rain_total_avg,
      ROUND(MIN(rainfall), 1) AS rain_total_min,
      ROUND(MAX(rainfall), 1) AS rain_total_max
    FROM
      (
        (
          SELECT
            MAX(rain_total) - MIN(rain_total) AS rainfall,
            substr(timestamp, 1, 8) AS YYYYDD
          FROM
            weather
          WHERE
            timestamp > 0
          GROUP BY
            substr(timestamp, 1, 8)
        ) AS T1
      )
    GROUP BY
      SUBSTR(YYYYDD, 1, 8)
  ) AS sor ON tar.timestamp = sor.timestamp
SET
  tar.rain_total_avg = sor.rain_total_avg,
  tar.rain_total_min = sor.rain_total_min,
  tar.rain_total_max = sor.rain_total_max
```

> `Error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') GROUP BY SUBSTR(YYYYDD,1, 8)) AS sor ON tar.timestamp = sor.timestamp SET tar.`

I already checked the query with several online check tools. All reported the code as okay.

What is wrong with the query?

I already checked the query with several online check tools. All reported the code as okay.

Comment: Suggestion, use a dbfiddle and post a link here

Comment: Remove the superfluous level of parentheses around your `T1` derived table.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the parantheses around T1 block:

```
UPDATE
  MinMaxAvg AS tar
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      SUBSTR(YYYYDD, 1, 8) AS timestamp,
      ROUND(AVG(rainfall), 1) AS rain_total_avg,
      ROUND(MIN(rainfall), 1) AS rain_total_min,
      ROUND(MAX(rainfall), 1) AS rain_total_max
    FROM
        (
          SELECT
            MAX(rain_total) - MIN(rain_total) AS rainfall,
            substr(timestamp, 1, 8) AS YYYYDD
          FROM
            weather
          WHERE
            timestamp > 0
          GROUP BY
            substr(timestamp, 1, 8)
        ) AS T1
    GROUP BY
      SUBSTR(YYYYDD, 1, 8)
  ) AS sor ON tar.timestamp = sor.timestamp
SET
  tar.rain_total_avg = sor.rain_total_avg,
  tar.rain_total_min = sor.rain_total_min,
  tar.rain_total_max = sor.rain_total_max
```

I found out that the windows based sql client "HeidiSQL" might be used to find syntax errors in queries.